# Transform a string so that numbers greater than 5 are represented as a sum of several numbers

Tags: string, algorithm, matlab

I need to transform a string relative to a certain value so

```
2 3 4 5 6 1 5 16
```

Become

```
2 3 4 5 0 5 1 5 0 5 5 5 1
```

So, `2 = 2`, `3 = 3`, `4 = 4`, `6 = 5` and `6 = 1`, `5 = 5` and `5 = 0`, `16 = 5 5 5 1`.

In this case, I transformed the line relative to `5`. I have no idea how to do it for now, so, there's no code yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expression replacement ([`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html)). You need [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid detecting the `6` in `16` as a single `6`.

```
x = '2 3 4 5 6 1 5 16';
y = regexprep(x, {'(?<!\d)5' '(?<!\d)6' '16'}, {'5 0' '5 1' '5 5 5 1'});
```

This gives

```
y =
2 3 4 5 0 5 1 1 5 0 5 5 5 1
```

Comment: ohhhh is this what the op meant :D I have the wrong understanding then XD

Comment: @GameOfThrows It's not really clear; their answer uses numbers whereas their question says "string"

Comment: I know, exactly, that's why I was asking :D

Answer (score 2):

I have the simple to write loopy method, mb someone can give you the none-loopy vectorized solution:

```
a = [2 3 4 5 6 1 5 16];
k = 5;
c = [];
for t = 1:size(a,2)
b = a(t)/k;
    if b >= 1
        cat1 = [repmat([k],floor(b),1)',mod(a(t),5)];
    else
        cat1 = a(t);
    end
    c = [c,cat1]
end
```

c is the solution:

```
>> c =   2     3     4     5     0     5     1     1     5     0 ...
```

k you can set to 5 or 4 or whatever number.

Comment: Your answer look better than mine, thank you!

Comment: @ValerikPunk you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I did everything in 2 minutes after asked.

```
data=[2 3 4 5 6 1 5 16];
    len=length(data);
    mass=zeros();
    j=1;
    for i=1:len
        if data(i)>5
        x=data(i);
        mass(j)=5;
        mass(j+1)=x-5;
        j=j+2;
        else
            if data(i)==5;
                mass(j)=5;
                mass(j+1)=0;
                j=j+2;
            else data(i)<5;
                mass(j)=data(i);
                j=j+1;
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: yeah, this works for your example, but what if you have 21? you will need to write another loop, and 210? well good luck with that. Read my solution, it is a simpler version that does not require continuous nested loops.

Comment: Ha, I understood. Yep, that's a problem I can't resolve yet. But your answer resolving it. The question is - why the first symbol is always 0? p.s. My fault, sorry, 0 was prelocated in c upper in a program.